# FileNotFoundException When Reading Bytes From Google Drive

Tags: vb.net, pdf, google-docs-api

I have a line of code that reads the bytes of a PDF in Google Drive to be used later by another function. This line works until it runs into a file named like so:

> 1234567_012368547-98884 Street Lane Test.pdf

I've tried passing it both in a String variable and as a String literal, but files like this always create the following FileNotFoundException message:

> 'C:\Users\JimJam\Documents\Project\GoogleDriveProject\GDriveDownload\bin\Debug\1234567_012368547-98884 Street Lane Test.pdf'.

This makes no sense because it's suppose to be looking in a GDrive folder, not my local project folder, which it does correctly for all other files in the exact same Google Drive folder.

```
Dim file As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("1234567_012368547-98884 Street Lane Test.pdf")
```

Comment: Do you have any way of giving the *full* path of the file in the Google Drive folder?

Comment: Yes. I use the Google Api along with saved environment variables of my GDrive to access the file's path. When debugging, I see the path and even download url for the specific file. Getting to it isn't a problem. For some reason the program defaults the my local machine on certains files though when it hits that line of code.

Comment: `File.ReadAllBytes` will only work with a local or UNC path. The documentation says as much. Any time you provide a relative path, it is assumed that you are referring to a file under the current working directory of the application, which is generally the same folder the EXE was run from but may not be and may change as the app runs. If you want to read that file then you MUST provide an unambiguous, absolute or relative, local path. That means that there must be a drive letter associated with your Google Drive and you must provide that in the path. Otherwise, it's not supposed to work.

Comment: wouldn't you have to do a web request and download the file? like the above have said you cant use system.io.file that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jmcilhinney and Danny James pointed out, System.IO.File was not the way to go with acquiring the stream since it expected the file to be stored locally on my machine. Instead, I used the following logic using the Google API:

```
Dim Service = New DriveService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With 
{.HttpClientInitializer = MyCredentials, .ApplicationName = 
"ApplicationName")})

Dim fileStream = Service.HttpClient.GetStreamAsync(downloadURL)
Dim streamResult = fileStream.Result
```